# Why request and response calls in my burp suite python plugin come in such random order?

Tags: python, burp-suite, plugins

So I am trying to write this burp plugin using jython and python for burp suite. Now in the processHttpMessage body, I found before a proper execution of the entire method takes place for one request message, it starts executing for another request message. Why is this? And how can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests are processed asynchronously in Burp, so every time the browser makes a new HTTP request it'll trigger your script. You cannot switch this behaviour off (it's integral to Burp's proxy engine) so your code will need to be thread-safe.

Comment: Any chance of a small example, I am pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: @5cr3Amer Sorry, I don't have the time to write one up. You're probably better off asking on the [Burp community forums](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/topics/719254-how-do-i-/questions).